# inet_pton inet_ntop roll your own

Tags: inet

Our code has to run on both SLES9 (old) and an even older version HPUX.
We're implementing IPv6 now, but inet_pton and inet_ntop do not exist on our HPUX, so have to roll our own.

S/W is in C++.  If I have an IPv6 address string, can someone provide the C/C++ equivalent of the above 2 methods?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look in your favorite libc source (preferably not HPUX's).

http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/resolv/inet_ntop.c, 
http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/resolv/inet_pton.c.

Answer (score 0):

Musl's implementation: [inet_ntop](https://github.com/bpowers/musl/blob/master/src/network/inet_ntop.c), [inet_pton](https://github.com/bpowers/musl/blob/master/src/network/inet_pton.c) (simpler than implementation from glibc).